# How disable nuget package restore when adding new MVC5 Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

In a MVC project using Visual Studio 2015, i have configured the references to use **dlls without using nuget**. But when i'm adding a new view (MVC5 View Page, MVC5 Partial Page, etc), visual studio automatically add nuget packages to the project that are already referenced. Why? Is there a way to disable nuget completly?

- Using Add -> View, my references are not altered and the packages are not downloaded
- Using Add -> MVC5 View Page, MVC Partial View or the other ones, Visual Studio add a packages.config and change the references to the newly downloaded libraries

[image]

Here's the package that VisualStudio add when i'm adding a new View :

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

- I have the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 but this behaviour was there before the update
- I added the line `<RestorePackages>false</RestorePackages>` to the project file without success